# Overhead introduced by JDBC while pulling data from remote sites?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I'm running v9.3 of Postgres and have a table, say, "tablex" with the following columns:

```
col0 integer not null
col1 integer not null
col2 real
col3 real
col4 real
col5 real
col6 real
col7 numeric(10,7)
col8 numeric(10,7)
col9 bigint not null
```

Now, I'm using a JDBC driver in order to transfer rows from a remote Postgres to a local instance and I'm wondering how much overhead (in bytes) would be introduced, roughly, for each row because of JDBC? Is the JDBC traffic compressed or...

Comment: I think this is impossible to tell without either an intimate knowledge of the PostgreSQL protocol and the JDBC driver, or would require running extensive tests. You also don't specify overhead compared to what.

Comment: Re: compression, you might be interested in [this thread on another site](http://postgresql.nabble.com/Compression-on-SSL-links-td2261205.html).

Comment: @Mark: I'm trying to figure out how much data that will travel a mobile connection given the given table structure over a given timewindow. I'm not looking for an exact figure but rather an estimate. If I could assume that the traffic would be, say, "x number of bytes/row" or "x % of the size for a row" I would be able to calculate an "ok" estimate. If this is impossible it would nevertheless be interesting to know how data is transferred using JDBC - in internal binary format or "plain text".

Comment: @Gord: thanks for the link - interesting read!

Comment: _"transferred using JDBC"_: JDBC is only an API for database drivers in Java. In this case you are asking about a specific implementation, the postgresql JDBC driver; as far as I know the PostgreSQL JDBC driver uses a text oriented protocol, not binary (but I'm not 100% sure about that). If you want to be sure, just fire up wireshark. That said, for mobile applications to transfer data, you should consider using a rest service (or other webservice) instead of using JDBC. The statelessness of rest is a better fit for mobile applications.

Comment: @Mark: I understand the benefits using REST as our central service is REST-based but the dataflow has to be based on JDBC for the time being until we get the opportunity to re-architecture the solution. The interim solution is what we got 'til this happens and that's the reason we need to figure out the amount of traffic. Given the input I've received here I'll try to come to a rough estimate.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigating this I decided to rely on 'vnstat' in order to solve the problem. Thanks to everybody for their efforts in trying to help me out.